# Power BI Calculated Column - Create SKU Status using Parameters and previous month

Tags: datetime, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a SKU status based on the SKU creation date and the number of units sold in the last 12 months. If the SKU status is inactive, it needs to stay inactive, otherwise continue using the logic.

Below if my current DAX calculated column, but I need to figure out a way to **make the SKU status remain Inactive once it becomes Inactive**:

```
SKU Status = IF(
    [Date_time_year]=2019,
    "",
    IF([Month_Diff]<12,
    "Active",
    IF(CALCULATE(MAX([Month_Diff]))<37,
    "Active",
    IF(Summary Facts'[Sales_Qty_L12M]<51,
    "Inactive",
    "Active"))))
```

Below is an example output:

[image: Data Output]

I've tried creating another calculated column and measure using previous SKU Status method, but I am getting a circular error.

Comment: Is `'Summary Facts'[Sales_Qty_L12M]` the same table as where the Calculated Column `SKU Status` is created? Can you share the actual data table(s) behind this visual? Isn't `CALCULATE(MAX([Month_Diff]))` just the same as `[Month_Diff]` ? What is the logic - if created within the last 3 years, active, otherwise if sold less than 51, inactive, else, active ?

Comment: Sorry I typed the incorrect parameter for the third statement, the correct is below:

`SKU Status = IF(
    [Date_time_year]=2019,
    "",
    IF([Month_Diff]<12,
    "Active",
    IF([Max_Months_since_creation])<37,
    "Active",
    IF(Summary Facts'[Sales_Qty_L12M]<51,
    "Inactive",
    "Active"))))`

The logic is basically, if the SKU was created within the past 3 years then active, if rolling 12 month sales quantity < 51 then inactive, else active.

The issue is, once the SKU becomes inactive, it needs to remain inactive.

Comment: Please share the data table this is based on. The headers will do and/or a snip of the data model with relevant relationships. Update your original question with the same.